# How can I solve the SecurityException error in Android 12?

Tags: android

I request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in real time

And it asks for gps information as below

There was no problem before, but I get a SecurityException error on certain devices using Android 12

Do you have any way to solve this problem?

I've searched several ways but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Does someone know how?

thank you

```
if(isGpsEnable(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
{
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsListener);  // error
}
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android 12 android improve privacy just look below thread to implement the latest way of getting location permission.

https://proandroiddev.com/android-12-privacy-changes-for-location-55ffd8c016fd

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are checking to see if the permission has been granted:

```java
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {

// do your GPS stuff here!

}
```